# Azure Media Services, GetLocators with V3 api and ODataQuery

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to get all the streaming locators for a given asset using the v3 API and the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media` package but I am getting a bad request error using Odata Queries:

It fails on this line: `var locator = client.StreamingLocators.List("webinars", "webinars", new ODataQuery<StreamingLocator>(x=>x.AssetName == assetId));`

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.ApiErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
```

When I use it without the ODataQuery, it returns fine.

```
public IList<string> GetLocatorForAsset() {
            var assetId = "bb4953cf-4793-4b3c-aed8-ae1bec88a339";
            IList<string> streamingUrls = new List<string>();      

            var locator = client.StreamingLocators.List("webinars", "webinars", new ODataQuery<StreamingLocator>(x=>x.AssetName == assetId));
            ListPathsResponse paths = client.StreamingLocators.ListPaths("webinars", "webinars", locator.FirstOrDefault().Name);

            foreach (StreamingPath path in paths.StreamingPaths) {
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
                uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
                uriBuilder.Host = "webinars-use2.streaming.media.azure.net";

                uriBuilder.Path = path.Paths[0];
                streamingUrls.Add(uriBuilder.ToString());
            }

            return streamingUrls;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Has this posted answer resolved any questions for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per media services filtering documentation, user can filter "Streaming Locators" only by "name", "properties.created" and "properties.endTime".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/entities-overview#streaming-locators

[image]

In your example, you are trying to filter using assetId/assetName which is not supported. hence 400 Bad request error. see detailed error example in postman

[image]

Here is the valid filtering example using Streaming Locator "name" tag.

NOTE : This is not an asset Tag

[image]

C# example used to successfully filter streaming locator using "name"

```
    try
    {
        // GUID need to be specified in single quote. using OData v 3.0
        var odataquery = new ODataQuery<StreamingLocator>("name eq '65a1cb0d-ce7c-4470-93ac-fedf66450ea0'");
        IPage<StreamingLocator> locators = client.StreamingLocators.List("mediatest", "mymediatestaccount", odataquery);

        Console.WriteLine(locators.FirstOrDefault().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(locators.FirstOrDefault().StreamingLocatorId);
        Console.WriteLine(locators.FirstOrDefault().Id);

        ListPathsResponse paths = client.StreamingLocators.ListPaths("mediatest", "mymediatestaccount", locators.FirstOrDefault().Name);

        foreach (StreamingPath path in paths.StreamingPaths)
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
            uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
            uriBuilder.Host = "webinars-use2.streaming.media.azure.net";

            uriBuilder.Path = path.Paths[0];
            Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

I hope this helps.